# Why can't I Insert my File object as comparable?

Tags: java, oop, object, comparable

I get an error in line with `theTree.insert(new File("a", 1));`: `The method insert(Comparable) in the type Tree is not applicable for the arguments (File)`.

And when I try to cast as such `theTree.insert((Comparable) new File("a", 1));` I get other error: E`xception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: File cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable at TreeApp.main(tree.java:134)`.

Why can't I pass this object?

My object:

```
class FileObject
{
    public String name;
    public int size;

    File(String a, int b)
    {
        this.name = a;
        this.size = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does java.io.File implements Comparable ? I guess not, how do you tell if two Files are equals ? By fileno? by file name ? Or by content ? I'd extend the File class implementing Comparable (thus taking a decision on what the compareTo() behaviour should be. (Sorry I was assuming File as the standard File class, but reasoning works as well for your class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement `Comparable<File>`

```
class File implements Comparable<File>
    {
        public String name;
        public int size;

        File(String passedName, int passedSize)
        {
            this.name = passedName;
            this.size = passedSize;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(File o) {
            //e.g Provide comparable on size
            return Integer.valueOf(size).compareTo(o.size);
        }
    }
```

References:

- [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

*Note: Please provide `compareTo` implementation in contract with `equals` method.*

Answer (score 7):

Because your `File` class does not implement `Comparable`.